# apache redirect to public ip

Tags: apache-2.2, active-directory

in a new job they have a problem with dns with split zone, because the web site is allocated in a public ip, they can not go to visit their webpage

in the domain i tries to point the www -> to the public ip 
but it doesn't work, but i download a web server in put it in the lan, and the www registry to a private ip, and it resolve

but how can i redirect the www record from my computer to a public ip
with apache server

www AD--------> my machine ---------> public ip

i don't know how to make that, please help!!

Comment: You're asking for nothing but headaches if your users need to reach their web server via "my machine". Can your users reach the web server by it's public IP address? (i.e. http://your.public.ip.address )  If "yes", then talk to your DNS admin about adding the webserver A record to the internal view.  If "no" talk to your network admins about why not.  Or talk to both your DNS admin and server admin about an internal interface for the webserver.

Comment: thanksm it's because in my country is not common the role by the staff member, so the person who implement the active directory make the mistake to put the same name and we are not able to see the webpage. So i tried to change the www record to the public ip, doesn't work, but i changed to a lan ip, and worked, thats the reason why i posted it